# Black background when display an image in a REST API with Spring

Tags: java, spring, image, file-io, inputstream

I want to return a link to the image (or the image itself) when making a `GET`-request. I saw the tutorial from Baeldung and decided to use it. The code looks like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/image-manual-response", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/images/image-example.jpg");
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Since I could not figure out what `servletContext` is and find the information I needed, I slightly changed the method:

```java
    @GetMapping("/image")
    public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(("C:\\Users\\vartanyan\\Desktop\\images\\Puer").getBytes());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

As a result, in Swagger I got the following:

[image]

And when I open the image in a separate window, I get the following:
[image]

How can this problem be corrected? I am writing `Rest` `MVC` app using `Spring Boot`, `Hibernate`, `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `FileInputStream()` realisation. For example:

```java
public void getDrinkImage(HttpServletResponse response, Long drinkId) throws IOException {

        String imageURL = drinkRepository.getById(drinkId).getImage();

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(uploadPath + imageURL);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the servletContext from the request, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/image")
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("images/Puer.jpg");
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Comment: `NullPointer` in variable `in`

Comment: You need to put your file in the application context (in your war/jar)

Comment: in the resources?

Comment: I added a folder with images to the `resources` folder. Now the path looks like this: `C:\Users\vartanyan\IdeaProjects\Coffeetearea\src\main\resources\images\Puer.jpg` but NullPointer too.
In Idea it looks like: `InputStream in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\vartanyan\\IdeaProjects\\Coffeetearea\\src\\main\\resources\\images\\Puer.jpg");`

Comment: `InputStream in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("images/Puer.jpg");` dont work

Comment: sorry, the folder should be webapp not resources. Put in  "src/main/webapp/images/Puer.jpg" use "images/Puer.jpg"

Comment: `NullPointer`. May be WEB-INF?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
@GetMapping("/image")
    public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\vartanyan\\Desktop\\images\\Puer");
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Comment: NullPointer. Variable `in` = `null`